# Select By Attribute and Export with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I have 4 folders with shapefiles in them, and for each folder I am selecting by attribute and then exporting the new shapefile.  My code runs with no error but the output folders have no files in them and I am not sure if the problem is the way I am selecting by attribute or the way I am exporting.  The code I am using is this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

folders=r'E:\Sheyenne\Landsat_8\spatial'
out=r'E:\Sheyenne\Landsat_8\just_field_cells'
basename=os.listdir(folders)
for i in basename:
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(out,i)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(out,i))
for folder in os.listdir(folders):
    arcpy.env.workspace=os.path.join(folders,folder)
    shapefiles=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
    for shape in shapefiles:
        name=shape[:-4]
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shape, "lyr")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_Selection", "FID_ = 233" or "FID_ = 604" or 
        "FID_ = 887" or "FID_ = 959" or "FID_ = 1686" or "FID_ = 1731" or "FID_ = 1753" or "FID_ = 1798"
        or "FID_ = 2058")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("lyr", out, name)
print "Done"
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your folder structure.. I'm not seeing how these paths fit together, you may be trying to get a ListFeatureClasses on a file or nonexistent folder. Note that you can make a feature layer with a where_clause - unless you're doing multiple selections against the layer there is no need for SelectLayerByAttribute as it can all be done with the make feature layer with where_clause. I see the input workspace changing but the out folder does not.

Comment: Within `folders` there are 4 folders.  I am setting the environment to each folder within `folders`.  That part works correctly.  When I print `shape` in `shapefiles` it prints as it should, so that shouldn't be where the problem is.  I use this structure to access files within sub-folders routinely.

Comment: your where_clause looks strange to me. try using the IN comparison : ' "FID_" IN (233, 604,887) '

Comment: that returns, `ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).`

Comment: Select_analysis is one tool that can replace three (MakeFeatureLayer, SelectLayerByAttribute and FCtoFC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that it's exporting but to the same directory and then overwriting or tripping up on the first iteration of `listdir`.. best to do all of it in one pass of `listdir`:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

folders=r'E:\Sheyenne\Landsat_8\spatial'
out=r'E:\Sheyenne\Landsat_8\just_field_cells'

for folder in os.listdir(folders):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folders,folder)): # only folders (directories) in folders
        outDir = os.path.join(out,folder)             # keep track of where it's going
        os.makedirs(outDir)                           # doesn't matter if it does or doesn't exist, make sure it's there

        arcpy.env.workspace=os.path.join(folders,folder)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Workspace is {0}, exporting to {1}".format(arcpy.env.workspace,outDir)) # follow the changing workspace
        shapefiles=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
        for shape in shapefiles:
            name=shape[:-4]
            arcpy.AddMessage("Shapefile {0}".format(shape))
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shape, "lyr")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_Selection", "FID_ in (233,604,887,959,1686,1731,1753,1798,2058)")
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("lyr", outDir, name)
```

When you use [os.listdir()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) it will return *all* files and folders in the given path, your use of [os.path.isdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077424/python-os-path-exists-vs-os-path-isdir) is incorrect and should be done like:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
```

First for checking if *something* exists and then finding out if the existing object is a folder, not for checking if a folder (path) exists.